# Trend Micro Causing IIS Slow Response

Tags: iis, anti-virus

I have a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 server with IIS serving up a static html page. I am using this to verify the performance of the server before deploying my web app. I use apache bench to test the the default website on the server. I get a response of +- 23 reqeusts/s. Serving up the same page using nginx on the same server, I get a response of > 300 requests per second.

Stopping the Trend Micro OfficeScan client services does not fix the problem. Uninstalling the OfficeScan client on the server results in the IIS response improving to more or less the same as the nginx response.  My guess is that the OfficeScan client is installing a driver or some other software that is affecting IIS. I have tried various methods to trace the cause of the problem, to no avail (wireshark, procmon, procexp, etc). Anyone had similar issues with Trend Micro? Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Trend Micro Server so I cannot change the scan options, but I doubt that this would make a difference since stopping the client does not affect the response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is most likely the issue for us as well, but @yuben, you mention that the process of disabling Proxy Hooking for the OfficeScan client are slightly different (that's the one we use), but I haven't been able to locate any documentation or settings to point to the correct way to do it for this client. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I would have responded with a comment but I don't have the reputation on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have seen similar issues with alot of our clients, and like you experienced the issue even after closing the Trend client.
We´ve narrowed it down to the the "Proxy hooking" module that Trend uses, and disabling this have improved our performance greatly.

The solution is to close the client (usually requires the Trend password from the server), running the disable tool, click choose module, select proxy hooking, and click disable.

(Note that the screenshot is from a PC that does NOT have trend installed)

[image: Trend disable module]

Comment: Thanks! You solution worked. Sorry for the late response - the corporate wheels turn slow! We use the OfficeScan client, so the method to disable the proxy hooking is slightly different, but the end result is that the response from IIS is approx 200X better!